# Javascript .click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm creating a store locator for a website and ive got a tooltip box that displays an email the i want to make a link. this is the html:

```
<div class="gm_popup">
    <span class="address"> Address</span><br>
    <span class="city"> City</span><br>
    <span class="phone"> 123 456</span><br>
    <span class="email"> email@example.com</span><br>
</div>
```

and this is the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var old_focus_and_popup = focus_and_popup;

  focus_and_popup = function (id){
    return_val = old_focus_and_popup (id);

    setTimeout(function (){
      jQuery("#store_map .gm_popup .email").click(function(){
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
      });

      jQuery(".gm_popup .email").css('text-decoration','underline').css('color','#2aa8e0');
    }, 200);
    return return_val ;
  }
});
```

any idea why this wouldnt be working? after adding some console.logs it seems like its getting as far as the .click but no going inside the function. Thanks

Comment: Why are you dynamically setting a `mailto:` function? Why not just define it as a hyperlink in the first place?

Comment: Why do you have the click event in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: its using shopify and the way its getting created is [email]. when you try put html around it it creates the whole span as a link rather than the value inside

Comment: @NickZ - https://boldapps.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202127896-How-do-I-make-the-email-address-clickable- thats where i got the code from

Comment: I hope you understand that setTimeout is only going to register the event, not actually execute it

Comment: i tried removing the setTimeout and still no luck

Comment: What is the original `focus_and_popup`? How is it being called? What are you expecting to happen exactly? Maybe there is a better way to handle this... Why is there a setTimeout? Is content being loaded dynamically?

Comment: the code you did post doesn't work `ReferenceError: focus_and_popup is not defined`

Comment: @sfiore because it is not all the code...

Comment: Why don't you use `bind` instead of `click` to attach your event handlers? Then you wouldn't need to wait until the popup is displayed to create the handler.

Comment: @Coin_op how do i bind instead of click?

Comment: You could look in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ 
Its fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering click event

This won't trigger until any click is done manually.

If you wanna get auto click then try like this after registering click event

```
jQuery("#store_map .gm_popup .email").click();
```

or

```
jQuery("#store_map .gm_popup .email").trigger("click");
```

Comment: it doesnt get inside the click function. ive put a console.log but its not displaying

Comment: @AlexMurray can you provide fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have all the events code inside the function, and you never end up calling that function. So I've made some changes, removed the setTimeout, as that was unnecessary. Also, made a call to that function.

```
<div id="store_map">
  <div class="gm_popup">
    <span class="address"> Address</span><br>
    <span class="city"> City</span><br>
    <span class="phone"> 123 456</span><br>
    <span class="email"> email@example.com</span><br>
</div>

</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){



  focus_and_popup = function (id){
    //return_val = old_focus_and_popup (id);


      jQuery("#store_map .gm_popup .email").click(function(){
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        console.log("HERE");
        document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
      });

      jQuery(".gm_popup .email").css('text-decoration','underline').css('color','#2aa8e0');

    return return_val ;
  }
  focus_and_popup();
   var old_focus_and_popup = focus_and_popup;
});
```

Comment: im getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: return_val is not defined any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you a snippet that simply works.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

       jQuery(".gm_popup .email").click(function () {
         alert('hello');
         var text = jQuery(this).text();
         document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
       });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gm_popup">
  <span class="address"> Address</span>
  <br>
  <span class="city"> City</span>
  <br>
  <span class="phone"> 123 456</span>
  <br>
  <span class="email"> email@example.com</span>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: its not getting into the click function for some reason

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you're creating an infinite loop between focus_and_popup and old_focus_and_popup..